# NodeJS net module consuming a lot of CPU

Tags: node.js

I've got a server which relies heavily on the `net` module. Its a TCP chat server.

When I'm profiling the app during a load of around 500 concurrent connections using `StrongLoop CPU Profiler` I notice that its the `net.js - line: 496` file thats using the most CPU. More specifically the function `onread`.

My server is very basic it receives JSON encoded strings which are parsed and it sends strings back to the clients.

Any ideas where I should start digging?